# Put array elements into individual variables

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am creating an array like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < mynumber; i++) {
    batch[i] = oSelectedItems[""+i].mAggregations.cells["0"].mProperties.title;
}
```

so my array `batch` can contain any number of lines. Now I need to create individual variables from the array, let's say:

```
var1 = batch[0],
var2 = batch[1]
```

and so on.

How can I achieve that when I do not know the number of lines?

Comment: Why would you need these variables? What is the purpose of variables being generated dynamically and accessed dynamically? What is the advantage of `var2` over `batch[1]`?

Comment: All computer programs are dynamic by definition.